# Marking a text field invalid from another text field's change event is undo'ed

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Here's a function assigned to the `change` event of `textfield` in my controller:

```
checkFields: function (field, ov, nv, e) {

    switch (field.name) {

        case 'currentPassword':
        case 'newPassword':
        case 'confirmNewPassword':
            //set button state depending on form's element values...
            var form = Utils.getCmp('form[itemId=changePasswordForm]');
            var values = form.getForm().getValues();

            if (values.newPassword != values.confirmNewPassword) {
                this.changePwdButton().setDisabled(true);
                this.utils.getCmp('textfield[name=confirmNewPassword]').markInvalid(this.strings.Messages.str_ErrorPwdMatch);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                this.utils.getCmp('textfield[name=confirmNewPassword]').markInvalid(false);
            }

            if (!form.isValid()) {
                this.changePwdButton().setDisabled(true);
                return false;
            }

            this.changePwdButton().setDisabled(false);
            return true;
            break;

    }
}
```

When this is triggered by the 'newPassword' textfield, the block that marks the `confirmNewPassword` as invalid works OK but when it's triggered by the `confirmNewPassword` itself, it works, but then is undo'ed (mark as valid) when the function returns...

If I follow the call stack when triggered via `confirmNewPassword` the code eventually reaches this in the framework:

```
checkChange: function() {
    if (!this.suspendCheckChange) {
        var me = this,
            newVal = me.getValue(),
            oldVal = me.lastValue;
        if (!me.isEqual(newVal, oldVal) && !me.isDestroyed) {
            me.lastValue = newVal;
            me.fireEvent('change', me, newVal, oldVal);
            me.onChange(newVal, oldVal); //this line undos prevous markInvalid()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it does that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the `onChange` function, which calls the `validate` function, and this function calls the `isValid` function!

```
onChange: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (this.validateOnChange) {
        this.validate();
    }
    this.checkDirty();
},

validate : function() {
    var me = this,
        isValid = me.isValid();
    if (isValid !== me.wasValid) {
        me.wasValid = isValid;
        me.fireEvent('validitychange', me, isValid);
    }
    return isValid;
},

isValid : function() {
    var me = this;
    return me.disabled || Ext.isEmpty(me.getErrors());
},
```

Your goal is, that the *Change Pwd Btn* is only enabled when both password fields have the same value!
Therefore you should override the `isValid` function, instead of listening to the change event.

By the way: Instead of using this `var form = Utils.getCmp('form[itemId=changePasswordForm]');` you should use, `var form = field.up('form[itemId=changePasswordForm]');` (Instead searching the whole  DOM, you are starting at your element and just search upwards!)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the markup for `confirmNewPassword` to:

```
{
    fieldLabel: strings.UI.str_ConfirmNewPassword,
    xtype: 'textfield',
    inputType: 'password',
    name: 'confirmNewPassword',
    validateOnChange: false //this line fixed it
}
```

And now it works.